# Is there a single adjective equivalent to "oddly satisfying"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I came across this typescale pictured below, and found the curve it makes to be quite satisfying in a way that reminded me of those "oddly satisfying" videos that go viral every now and then.

It made me wonder if there's a particular adjective that describes that feeling specifically? "Satisfying" feels a little too broad.

[image]

Comment: I could see situations where `oddly` would be used as `unexpected` in which case `Serendipitous - occurring or discovered by chance in a happy or beneficial way.` might be along the lines of what you're looking for.

Comment: @Shelby115 while I agree that there are circumstances where `oddly` could be used as `unexpected`, I don't think serendipitous describes this particular scenario, insofar as I don't think chance was a factor.

Comment: If, instead of a single word, you'll accept a phrase, I suggest that the illustration *scratched an itch you didn't know you had*.